# Custom Function Not Defined Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I made this custom function and put it outside globally which normally would work. I also tried moving it inside the main async puppeteer function but also doesn't work. Its a simple function. In each page evaluate function I call this and pass the selector. But, its saying not defined and promise rejection which is weird because the function isn't a promise....Please help

```
const grabDomConvertNodlistToArray = (grabDomHtmlPath) => {
  // grabbing node list from html selector all
  const nList = document.querySelectorAll(grabDomHtmlPath);
  // converting nodelist to array to be returned
  const array = Array.from(nList);
  return array;
};
```

I tried turning the function into an async function adding a new parameter page. I then added async to my evaluate function and then passes the puppeteer page as an argument and still errors and not working.

```
const grabDomConvertNodlistToArray = async (page, grabDomHtmlPath) => {
  try {
    // grabbing node list from html selector all
    const nList = await page.document.querySelectorAll(grabDomHtmlPath);
    // converting nodelist to array to be returned
    const array = Array.from(nList);
    return array;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

So I have your typical puppeteer setup where you awai browser.newPage() then you goto(url). Then i added this;

await page.exposeFunction("grabDomConvertNodlistToArray", grabDomConvertNodlistToArray);

added async to my evaluate callback function aka async() => {}. But still when calling my custom function inside the above evaluate function it doesn't work for some reason.

---

Found A Solution But, It Doesn't Work For Me. I'm Getting array.forEach is not a method which indicates to me that inside my grabDomConvertNodlistToArray function its not grabbing the nodeList or converting it into an array. If it did then forEach would be a function.

[Solution 3](https://www.py4u.net/discuss/296762)

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto(someURL);       

var functionToInject = function(){
    return 1+1;
}

var otherFunctionToInject = function(input){
    return 6
}

await page.exposeFunction("functionToInject", functionToInject)
await page.exposeFunction("otherFunctionToInject", otherFunctionToInject)

var data = await page.evaluate(async function(){
    console.log('woo I run inside a browser')
    return await functionToInject() + await otherFunctionToInject();
});

    return data
```

So erase the two functions above and convert it to use my function below.

```
const grabDomConvertNodlistToArray = (grabDomHtmlPath) => {
    // grabbing node list from html selector all
    const nList = document.querySelectorAll(grabDomHtmlPath);
    // converting nodelist to array to be returned
    const array = Array.from(nList);
    return array;
  };
```

Running my js file results in an error of array.forEach isn't a function which is weird because if the function worked as intended the const array inside my evaluate function would be an array because its = to the above function which is returning an array. So.....idk whats going on think it has something to do with the document.querySelectorAll() line.

```
const rlData = async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch(
    {
      headless: true,
    },
    {
      args: ["--flag-switches-begin", "--disable-features=OutOfBlinkCors", "--flag-switches-end"],
    }
  );

const pageBodies = await browser.newPage();
  await pageBodies.goto("https://test.com/bodies", {
    waitUntil: "load",
  });

  const grabDomConvertNodlistToArray = (grabDomHtmlPath) => {
    // grabbing node list from html selector all
    const nList = document.querySelectorAll(grabDomHtmlPath);
    // converting nodelist to array to be returned
    const array = Array.from(nList);
    return array;
  };

  await pageBodies.exposeFunction("grabDomConvertNodlistToArray", grabDomConvertNodlistToArray);

  const rlBodyNames = await pageBodies.evaluate(async () => {
    // grabs all elements in html to make nodelist & converts it to an array
    const array = grabDomConvertNodlistToArray(".testbodies > div > h1");
    // push the data collected from array into data array and returned
    const data = [];
    array.forEach((element) => {
      data.push(element.textContent);
    });
    return data;
  });
}
rlData();
```

Guess I'm going to have to move the document.querySelectorAll functionality out of the custom function and back in the evaluate. However, the whole reason of making that custom function was to reduce the same code being used multiple times since my overall crawler is 238 lines long with a lot of repetitiveness. Not being able to call custom functions like mine is horrible for refactoring same code executions.

I gave up trying to get this to work and decided just to do it this way. Yeah it makes your code repetitive if you have more pages to scrape so you will be using the same code many times which is what I was trying to avoid but, puppeteer is the worse for refactoring your code maybe down the line the developers of said package will add the ability to easily use custom functions like how I was trying too.

```
const testNames = await pageBodies.evaluate(() => {
    const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll(".test > div h2");
    const array = Array.from(nodeList);
    const data = [];
    array.forEach((element) => {
      data.push(element.textContent);
    });
    return data;
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exposeFunction()` is not suitable for your case: the exposed function is intended to tranfer data between browser and Node.js contexts so it can be wrapped under the hood in a code that serialize and deserialize arguments and returned data and some unserializable data (as DOM elements) can be lost. Try this instead:

```js
const rlData = async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch(
    {
      headless: true,
    },
    {
      args: ["--flag-switches-begin", "--disable-features=OutOfBlinkCors", "--flag-switches-end"],
    }
  );

  const pageBodies = await browser.newPage();

  await pageBodies.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {
    window.grabDomConvertNodlistToArray = function grabDomConvertNodlistToArray(grabDomHtmlPath) {
      // grabbing node list from html selector all
      const nList = document.querySelectorAll(grabDomHtmlPath);
      // converting nodelist to array to be returned
      const array = Array.from(nList);
      return array;
    }
  });

  await pageBodies.goto("https://test.com/bodies", {
    waitUntil: "load",
  });

  const rlBodyNames = await pageBodies.evaluate(() => {
    // grabs all elements in html to make nodelist & converts it to an array
    const array = grabDomConvertNodlistToArray(".testbodies > div > h1");
    // push the data collected from array into data array and returned
    const data = [];
    array.forEach((element) => {
      data.push(element.textContent);
    });
    return data;
  });
}
rlData();
```

Comment: O okay, but the way my scraper works is after page.Bodies is done I open a new page and goto a new url and repeat the top with a different html path. So that function would only work on pageBodies right? then would have to repeat that whole function again in another page which would defeat the purpose of refactoring the code if I have to repeat it like 5 more times. I'm wanting to be able to call that function in all my pages that I am using and only have it in the code one time.

Comment: That should be an easy fix though just need to rename all my evaluates to the main browser and not open a new one after each one is done. Then I will be able to call that function inside all my evaluate functions since its in the same browser and only one browser instead of like 5 new browsers.

Comment: So added your function code and when hovering over the function it gives me this error
 ![image](https://i.gyazo.com/66f74a62951348c81f0f4db0fae3a2f8.png).

Comment: Guess that error didn't matter it still ran without errors in terminal umm werid. Thanks so much for the help this one was really driving me crazy. Also, the puppeteer docs for that method doesn't really explain that you can use it like this.